# " I guess you could say that" as a reply =?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-usage

What people exactly mean when they say " I guess you can/could say that ... " or reply with " I guess you could say that. " ?

I mean if it doesn't need any further context to be provided here.

Comment: Some context would be helpful, for example, a complete sentence.

Comment: [What do people mean when they say...questions require an auxiliary verb unless the verb is to be]

Comment: What is it about the reply in particular that's confusing? (Is it the use of *guess* or *could*?)

Comment: It usually carries at least *slight* overtones of "reluctant agreement". Somewhat along the lines of *I can't argue with what you say (although really I would **like** to),* or *I wouldn't phrase it as [bluntly / crudely / simplistically / etc.] as you just did, but broadly speaking you are correct.*

Comment: "I guess/suppose you could say that" is often a polite way of saying "I don't agree with you" or "you are talking nonsense".

Comment: ...but I'm closevoting as "Unclear what you're asking". It's complete nonsense to say *it doesn't need any further context to be provided [in the question text]*. More or less ***by definition***, the cited utterance comes immediately after someone else saying something (it ***cannot*** be used to initiate a conversation, in any context). If we have no idea who that was or what they said, how can we meaningfully evaluate the ***response**?*